# XSD to support top element with different names

Tags: xml, xsd

I need an XSD to support an XML that may have different top element name, but all elements within XML are the same.

Not sure if possible, worth asking.

For example:

```
<abc>
  <name></name>
  <address></address>
  <phone>
    <home></home>
    <cell></cell>
  </phone>
</abc>
```

---

```
<xyz>
  <name></name>
  <address></address>
  <phone>
    <home></home>
    <cell></cell>
  </phone>
</zyx>
```

---

Example XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="abc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>
        <xs:element name="phone">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="home"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cell"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, simply name the `complexType`, define it globally, and reference it in the declarations of the possible root elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="abc" type="CommonType"/>
  <xs:element name="xyz" type="CommonType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="CommonType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>
      <xs:element name="phone">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="home"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cell"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```